# Changing ExecutionContext of a Future after initialisation

Tags: scala, future

I understand ["ExecutionContext is like a cockroach"](https://medium.com/@sderosiaux/are-scala-futures-the-past-69bd62b9c001#a10c):

> We can’t talk about Futures without talking about its
>   ExecutionContext: they form a duo (unfortunately)... It means the
>   ExecutionContext was decided early on (generally on startup) and
>   therefore is fixed. But callers should be able to decide on which
>   ExecutionContext they want to run your function (like using their
>   own). It’s not the responsibility of the callee service to enforce it
>   (exceptions aside).

and we have to pass it in at construction time as implicit argument

```
object Future {
  def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext)
}
```

and if we want to have full control in which thread pool the task executes we should use libraries like cats-effect.

Nevertheless, I was wondering is there any way at all we could hack a **lazy** initialised `Future` to make it run on a different execution context from the one it was initialised with? Perhaps some hideous reflective black magic, where we somehow identify the task and steal it from the queue it was put in?

For example, say we have a function which accepts a pass-by-name `Future`

```
def foo(f: => Future) = {
  val differentExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(...
  /* run f on differentExecutionContext */
}

foo(Future(42)(ExecutionContext.Implicits.global))
```

Now what we could do is at call site use different execution context like so

```
val differentExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(...
foo(Future(42)(differentExecutionContext))
```

however, this forces the user to remember to provide and use a different execution context. Is there any way `Future(42)` could run on `differentExecutionContext` inside `foo` instead of `global`, transparently to the user?

<sub>In case this is an XY problem, here is [context](https://github.com/guardian/tip/pull/61).</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's possible. `=> Future[T]` is indistinguishable from just `Future[T]` when it comes to hacking. I imagine you'd like to do something like that:

`f.asInstanceOf[SomeImplOfFuture[T]].setExecutionContext(myContexty)`.

But any such action would trigger execution of `f`.